# Set the cell title to bold when selected

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a tableview  built-in in a more complex modal dialog. Before showing the dialog, I provide the index of the selected cell externally and the dialog processes in tv:willDisplayCell: that so that the right cell has the bold font. But when the dialog finally pops up, I need to allow this also to change as I select some other row.
I am probably missing something but how would I do this? How would I set the selected cell title font to bold?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font in the appropriate delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip
{
    UITableViewCell *c = [tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
    c.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]; // for example
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this robust you will need to store the index of the selected cell in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` not just update the cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSIndexPath *previousIndexPath = self.selectedIndexPath;
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ previousIndexPath, indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Now both the previously selected cell and the newly selected cell will be reloaded and your current implementation of making the text bold should work assuming that you do it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with some kind of

```
if ([indexPath isEqual:self.selectedIndexPath]) {
  // bold
} else {
  // not bold
}
```

The reason this is more robust than simply updating the cell in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is because if you scroll the cell off screen when it comes back on it will be correctly highlighted. Here we are updating the model not just the view.